# How do I search for end of line ('\n') in a UTF-8 text?

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

I have a C++ library that provides an I/O device interface (including an implementation for files). It also provides a UTF-8 string class. Now, I just need to read a line from this `IODevice`. The reason I'm mentioning this library is I can't, for example, open the file with `std::ifstream` and read it using something like `std::wbuffer_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>>`. I don't mind using stdlib (in fact, I prefer it), but I do need to read the line from my `IODevice` and return it as my `String`.

Now, the specific question: if I read the file byte by byte, is it safe to assume that any byte with value `'\n'` is in fact a new line symbol, and not the trailing part of some different multi-byte symbol?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it safe to assume that any byte with value `'\n'` is in fact a new line symbol, and not the trailing part of some different multi-byte symbol?

Yes, in UTF-8, all ASCII bytes do not occur in non-ASCII code points.

Answer (score 6):

Just to add on what @Yu Hao said, UTF8 is actually backward compatible with ASCII, it cannot break it in any sort.

here is the reason why : UTF8 dictate that any ASCII characters will retain their bit-representation from ASCII, and this causes their leading bit to be always `0`.

any non-ascii character will be encoded to 2-4 bytes, and their leading bits will always start with `1` (the first byte will have consecutive sequence of `1` as the number of bytes needed to represented the characters, followed by `0`, the rest of the bytes will start with `10`).

this encoding pattern assures that ASCII characters canot be mixed with non-ASCII encoded sequences.